# What makes ammonia to dissociate when volume is increased?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, equilibrium

What makes ammonia dissociate to $\ce{N2}$ and $\ce{H2}$ when the volume is increased (pressure is reduced)?

I understand how pressure affects equilibrium. What happens after the $\ce{NH3}$ is being formed, then the pressure is reduced, for example, does the existence of a certain value of pressure is necessary for the formation of the $\ce{N-H}$ bond?

Also, the dissociation reaction is endothermic, where does the $\ce{NH3}$ get the energy to absorb so it gets dissociated?

Comment: The system moves in the direction to remove stress. After NH3 is formed, pressure is reduced but the presence of heat can be reduced also by moving back to the endothermic reaction recreating some N2/H2.

Comment: Without energy input, whether from heat, ultraviolet light, ionizing radiation or other source, NH3 is stable. If you're thinking of its *synthesis*, consider the starting temperature in the Haber process.

Comment: This your statement *I understand how pressure affects equilibrium.* kind of contradicts the whole question. Equilibrium means both forward and backward reactions are ongoing by the same rate ( which can be very low at low temperature a/o without catalyst). Decreasing pressure makes ammonia decomposition going faster than synthesis.

Comment: The reaction of molecular nitrogen and hydrogen would not lead directly to formation of ammonia, the mechanism resulting in ammonia is more complex than a bimolecular process. However, if you consider the encounter of nitrogen and hydrogen only as the first step in the forward reaction to ammonia, you can explain the effect of increased pressure by understanding that increased pressure correlates with increased concentration at constant T, and therefore increased collisions.

Comment: The equilibrium constant $K$ is, well, constant at fixed temperature.  By working out the degree of dissociation $x$ of hydrogen which is also degree of ammonia formation we find that $K=f(x)/p^2$ where $f(x)$ (complicated polynomial in $x$) increases with $x$. So, if $p$ decreases so must $x$ (degree of dissn) decrease to keep $K$ constant and maintain the equilibrium. Even in an endothermic reaction there is a small but finite chance of crossing the energy barrier.